# How to use NSZombie?

Tags: nszombie

So I just finished my app and I wanted to as the final few steps run some diagnostics on it. In terms of what its memory usage, allocations, leaks, etc are.

I have a few questions:
1) Is there a standard list of instruments/checks I should run on my app be fore its submitted to make sure its robust? If so could someone point me to some links and/or tell me some names so I can google the stuff.

2) One of the tools I know to run is NSZombieEnabled. I followed the steps I found online on some sites to set up this NSZombie test but it doesn't seem to be working. I looked at this site: [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

This is what my XCode looks like after I tried the steps listed there:
[image]

[image]

But why is the zombies choice not highlighted?

Once I get it to work how do I actually use NSZombies?

Answer (score 0):

So far from what I know, NSZombies is only available for debugging Mac apps or ios apps running on the simulator. It cannot be used for apps running on i devices.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215176/xcode-instruments-enable-nszombie-detection-where-is-it) thread and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584919/can-not-enable-nszombieenabled).